# Python Eve - How to filter by datetime value

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

How can I return items filtered by date or date interval? 
I was trying something like this based on the filtering example from eve's [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#filtering):

```
/records/?where={"date": {"$gte": "2016-10-17"}}
```

I was thinking this python syntax could work too by checking this comment in eve's request parsing [code](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/io/mongo/parser.py#L21-L23):

```
/records/?where=date==datetime('2016-10-16')
```

But the result is 500 internal error, maybe the syntax is wrong. I'm having a hard 
time getting it right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/records?where={"date": {"$gt": "Mon, 17 Oct 2016 03:00:00 GMT"}}
```

It uses the `DATE_FORMAT` setting which defaults to RFC1123.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Nicola. Since I'm using `DATE_FORMAT` as `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %z'` I've tried querying with this format using `/records/?where={"date": {"$gte": "17/10/2015 00:00:00 -0200"}}` and it worked!